# JMH problem - measurements aren't correct

Tags: java, jmh

Here is my code:

```
public class JmhBenchmark {
@Param({"8", "16", "32"})

@State(Scope.Thread)
public static class st {

    public static Board br;
    public static int rowStart;
    public static int colStart;
}

@Setup(Level.Trial)
public void generateBoard() {
    st.br = new Board(boardSideSize);
    st.rowStart = 2 + (int) (Math.random() * (st.br.sideSize()));
    st.colStart = 2 + (int) (Math.random() * (st.br.sideSize()));
    st.br.insert(st.rowStart, st.colStart, 1); // first traveled node
}

@Benchmark 
public void generateTour(Blackhole bh) {
    bh.consume(Tour.solve(st.rowStart, st.colStart, 2, st.br));

}

public static void executeTest() {
    new JmhBenchmark().startBenchmark();

}

public void startBenchmark() {

    try {
        Options opt = new OptionsBuilder()
                .include(JmhBenchmark.class.getSimpleName())
                .forks(1)
                .build();
        new Runner(opt).run();
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    executeTest();
}

public class Tour{

public static int sideSize;
public static Board br;
public static int rowStart;
public static int colStart;
public static List<Tuple<Integer, Integer>> coord = new ArrayList<>();

static boolean solve(int row, int column, int count, Board br) {
    if (count > br.totalSize()) {
        return true;
    }

    List<int[]> nbrs = br.neighborsList(row, column);

    if (nbrs.isEmpty() && count != br.totalSize()) {
        return false;
    }

    Collections.sort(nbrs, new Comparator<int[]>() {
        public int compare(int[] x, int[] y) {
            return x[2] - y[2];
        }
    });

    for (int[] n : nbrs) {
        row = n[0];
        column = n[1];
        br.insert(row, column, count);
        coord.add(new Tuple(row - 2, column - 2));
        if (!br.orphanDet(count, row, column)
                && solve(row, column, count + 1, br)) {
            return true;
        }
        br.insert(row, column, 0);
    }

    return false;
}
}
```

I have `solve(rowStart, colStart, 2, br)` function, which solves knights tour problem. It problem formulated as follow: 
You have a (n x n) chessboard, empty but for a single knight on some square. Your task is to emit a series of legal knight moves that result in the knight visiting every square on the chessboard exactly once. 
So I'm testing solve function depending on board size (n x n). Possible n values are 8, 16 and 32. The problem is that the result of JMH measurement isn't appropriate. For ex.:

```
(boardSideSize)  Mode  Cnt  Score   Error  Units
             8  avgt    5  0,021 ± 0,001  us/op
            16  avgt    5  0,021 ± 0,001  us/op
            32  avgt    5  0,053 ± 0,004  us/op
```

When board's side size (n) is 8 or 16 measurements are equal. I have no idea what I'm doing incorrectly.

As well as, I tried this example, but it doesn't work:

```
(boardSideSize)  Mode  Cnt  Score   Error  Units
            64  avgt    5  0,051 ± 0,006  us/op
             8  avgt    5  0,026 ± 0,001  us/op
            16  avgt    5  0,022 ± 0,001  us/op
            32  avgt    5  0,053 ± 0,005  us/op
```

Tested with:
Java JDK 8 & JMH 1.22

Comment: Perhaps you should edit to add a mention of which version of Java & JMH is in use.

Comment: Basil Bourque, tested with: Java JDK 8 &
JMH 1.22

Comment: Please provide MCVE: full self-contained project one can compile and run. Your current code would not even compile due to dangling `@Param` annotation, which should have been over the field. From the experience, it is rather unlikely to be a JMH bug, but likely to be the disconnect about the expectation how the benchmark should perform, and how it actually performs.